# Cannot append data to file no matter what I do

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, encode

My code is the following:

```
generated_quote = '  '.join(generated) + '\n'
    generated_quote = str(generated_quote).encode('utf-8')
    with open("generated_quotes.txt", 'a') as f:
        f.write(generated_quote)
```

I’ve looked for answers on the Internet but all I could get was either “encode it,” (which I did), or use ‘a’ instead of ‘w’ in the open statement (which I also did). The error this program produces is the following:

```
write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

I’ve tried many combinations of many fixes, but I can’t get it to work no matter what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you remove the encoding line?

Comment: @Loocid It produces this error: ‘ascii’ codec cannot encode character ‘\u2015’

Answer (score 1):

When you encode a string like you did with `.encode('utf-8')`, you end up with a byte string.

To be able to write (or append) a byte string to a file you need to open the file with the binary flag. So instead of `a` you should use `ab` like so:

```
generated_quote = '  '.join(generated) + '\n'
generated_quote = str(generated_quote).encode('utf-8')
with open("generated_quotes.txt", 'ab') as f:
    f.write(generated_quote)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, greatly appreciated! :D